# Android App Crashes on Startup Runtime Exception

Tags: java, android

I don't have any errors in the code, but when I run the app it crashes. Here's a pic of the log. http://postimg.org/image/bbcovjovn/  I can't figure out what's wrong in the code.

MyBowlingScoresApplication.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Application;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MyBowlingScoresApplication extends Application {

    private ArrayList<BowlingScores> allBowlingScores;
private SQLiteDatabase bowlingScoresDB;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        BowlingScoresDatabaseHelper databaseHelper1 = new BowlingScoresDatabaseHelper(this);


        bowlingScoresDB = databaseHelper1.getWritableDatabase();

        //TODO get the data out of the database
        allBowlingScores = new ArrayList<BowlingScores>();  
    }

    public void addBowlingScores(BowlingScores bowlingScores){
        assert bowlingScores != null;

        allBowlingScores.add(bowlingScores);
    }

    public ArrayList<BowlingScores> getAllBowlingScores() {
        return allBowlingScores;
    }

    private void setAllBowlingScores(ArrayList<BowlingScores> allBowlingScores) {
        this.allBowlingScores = allBowlingScores;
    }


}
```

BowlingScoresDatabaseHelper.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class BowlingScoresDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



public static final int DB_VERSION = 1; 
public static final String DB_NAME = "MyBowlingScores.SQLite";
public static String BOWLING_SCORES_TABLE="BowlingScoresTable";
public static String RECORD_ID="ID";
public static String DATE = "Date";
public static String GAME1 = "Game1";
public static String GAME2 = "Game2";
public static String GAME3 = "Game3";



    public BowlingScoresDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bowlingScoresDB) {
    String sqlStatement = "create table " + BOWLING_SCORES_TABLE
            + " ("
            + RECORD_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement not null,"
            + DATE + " integer,"
            + GAME1 + " integer,"
            + GAME2 + " integer,"
            + GAME3 + " integer,"
            + ");";


Log.d("Bowling Database", sqlStatement);

    bowlingScoresDB.execSQL(sqlStatement);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: post your sqlite database helper class

Comment: you have pasted both the classes same... please post your BowlingScoresDatabaseHelper class

Comment: Please post your logcat (not a picture, but the actual logcat)

Comment: Problem in your database creation.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of the SQLite query is wrong:

```
create tableBowlingScoresTable...
```

Should be something like:

```
create table BowlingScoresTable...
```

Forgot a space?

Edit:

Okay you've supplied code now. Another syntax error I can see is:

`+ GAME3 + " integer,"` There shouldn't be a comma in the end since a `)` follows.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. I updated my code above because I accidentally posted the same class twice.

Comment: @dfasfsd It is an issue indeed! Does it still crash?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [getting familiar with Android's wide set of debugging tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html). You would have been able to easily pinpoint the cause of your problem by inspecting the stack trace in Logcat, or viewing the call hierarchy when the crash occurred while the debugger was attached.

The stack trace clearly illustrates that the SQL statement for creating your table contained invalid syntax. I spot two problems:

1. A missing space after "create table", and
2. An unexpected comma after the last column definition.